# Is there a way to pause and restart a thread or kill a thread and start it again?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

The project I am working on involves threading using a while loop which web scrapes stock prices from a website and plots this on a matplotlib graph.

I am now trying enable the user to change the stock they chose, but in order to do so I need to stop/pause/kill the thread so that the user can enter the new stock and then restart/start a new thread with the new chosen stock.

I am struggling to figure out how I can start the thread again or continue it as I have managed to 'pause' it by using a flag in the while loop of the thread that stops it from actually displaying anything but I am assuming this is bad practice because the thread is still active.

Here is the code for how I have paused the thread and what I tried to restart it:

```
stock_thread = threading.Thread(target=fetch_stock_price) #The thread itself
```

```
while True:

      if not stop_thread: #The while loop within the thread to see if it has been flagged to stop
        ...
else:
        break
```

```
if stock_thread.is_alive():
      stock_thread.join() #I know that this doesn't work and I cannot figure out what to do instead
    else:
      stock_thread.start()
```

In summary, the program has a button which generates a graph for the stock and a button which changes the stock. The button that generates the graph is bound to a command which starts the thread using stock_thread.start() and the change stock button should stop/kill/pause the thread using:

```
global stop_thread
    stop_thread = True
```

and then recall the same command bounded to the generate graph button to restart the thread.

I am getting an error saying that the a thread can only be started once, is there a way to work around this in the context of my project?

Thanks

Comment: A pause flag is fine IMO. You could use a `threading.Event()` for it to make it more efficient.

Comment: Killing a thread should be avoided: https://stackoverflow.com/q/323972/5378816

Comment: Like @AKX said, setting a flag that tells a thread to pause or kill _itself_ is OK. But, if you _forcibly_ pause or kill a thread, which is allowed by some threading systems, but not by all of them, then you have no way to know what the thread was doing at that moment. Other threads could be waiting for it to do something such as release a mutex. And, even if there was a way to break the lock, the killed thread could have been half-way through changing some data structure, which would leave the structure in a corrupted state for other threads to see.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Happily, Python doesn't have that functionality.